# How to solve the recursion $f(n+2)=3f(n+1)-2f(n)+5$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

$$f(n+2)=3f(n+1)-2f(n)+5, \text{ with } f(1)=4, f(2)=5\\ 
f(n+2)=3f(n+1)-2f(n)+n, \text{ with } f(1)=4, f(2)=5$$

I can't find anywhere the solution for sequences of this type and am unable to figure out how to solve them.

Please help me with an explicit solution. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE. I've edited your question using MathJax, our maths renderer. Check the source (by clicking [edit]) to see how it works. For further information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(m)=g(m)+am+b$

$\implies g(n+2)+a(n+2)+b=3[g(n+1)+a(n+1)+b]-2[g(n)+an+b]+5$

$\iff g(n+2)+an+(2a+b)=3g(n+1)-2g(n)+an+3a+b+5$

Set $2a+b=3a+b+5\iff a=-5$ to get $g(n+2)-3g(n+1)+2g(n)=0$

Then  follow [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving)

Comment: Thank you for ur time mate but i have a few more questions. :) for the solution of the second sequence i shall use the same method? and for the first sequence after i find the roots of the characteristic equation r=1 or r=2 and write down g(n)=A+B(2^n) then what?

Comment: @Somber, You can safely put distinct questions as independent post

Comment: @Somber, So, we have $f(n)=A+B2^n-5n+b$ . Now use the initial values to identify the constants

Comment: yes but i can only find B=3 what about A?

Comment: @Somber, $$4=f(1)=2B+b-5-A\ \ \ \ (1)$$ and $$5=f(2)=4B+b-10+A\  \ \ \ (2)$$  $$(2)-(1)\implies1=2B\implies4=1+b-5-A\iff b=A+8$$

Comment: got it thanks...